# Update multi array fields with mongo DB

Tags: .net, arrays, mongodb, updates

Here is my structure :
[image: structure example]

```
M 1 ---->
   Produits Array ----->
               0 ----->
                  ----> Id: 0
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 1
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 2
                  ----> Status : 0
               1 ----->
                  ----> Id: 3
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 4
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 5
                  ----> Status : 0
               2 ----->
                  ----> Id: 6
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 7
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 8
                  ----> Status : 0
M 2 ---->
   Produits Array ----->
               0 ----->
                  ----> Id: 9
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 10
                  ----> Status : 0
                  ----> Id: 11
                  ----> Status : 0
```

As you can see, the `Produits` fields in the main objects are an array of objects.
Now I would like to update all `Status` fields of the objects inside each `Produits` array where the reference is `2172, 2173, etc.` to the value -1

I search on internet and everything I found is some `foreach` methods which is not providing fast performance for a server.

I also tried with the operator `$`. But as described in the Mongo documentation, it's only matching the first element of an array. So it won't work if I have more than one element.

So I would like to know if someone has an good idea to update multi item's fields inside an array ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This sounds like a job for [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). (I know you said you tried the positional operator, but you didn't detail how.)</strike>

So, something like this should work:

```
db.<some collection>.update({products:{$elemMatch:{reference:2172}}}, {$set:{'products.$.status':-1}})
```

Since `{multi:true}` won't work because each sub document is under one document, I think you have have only two options:

1. Pull each document that matches the `$elemMatch` query into your
   application, edit it, and save it back.
2. Consider moving your subdocuments to their own collection so that your update will work.

Comment: this would update only one element in the array, even if multiple elements matched the condidtion {reference:2172}.  the positional operator returns the first element matching the query criteria

Comment: @AnandJayabalan D'oh, I see. `{multi:true}` won't work because all of these subdocuments are under one document...

Comment: yeah but in fact, my goal is to limit the call to mongo server at only 1. I would like to do it in one query that I will launch from my .net application. I agree with your first idea. But in my example, I have two documents... When I'll use the app, I might have 1000 or 5000 documents to edit. I feel it's not so good in the point of performance to do a first request to get the documents, iterate through them and save them back to the database.

Comment: @AdrienA. I believe a cursor will still work for you. This way you are not pulling them all into the app at once. Or, you can store a custom js function in mongo. I see you have already found that solution.

Comment: yeah but it is very slow in terms of performance.... : 3 minutes for updating 1000 rows... it is not possible with this way

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a "solution" by using a stored function :

```
function UpdateStatusProduits (produitsReference, status) {
    if (produitsReference.length === 0) {
        return;
    }

    produitsReference.forEach(function(reference) {
        db.Prodel.update(
            {"Produits.Reference": reference},
            { $set: { "Produits.$.Status": NumberInt(status)}}
        );
    });
}
```

It is working, but the performance is not so good as a query... anyway, it is one way, but it can't be consider as a final solution when there are requirements about performance. I ask anybody who find a better solution to provide it on this post.